# Prevent validation from running if field rendering is set to false

Tags: visualforce, validation

I have a zipcode input field on a visualforce page. This field could be hidden (rendered = false) based on certain needs. I have the following field validation to ensure a proper zipcode format is entered. If the zip code field is hidden the validation runs when trying to save the record. I need it to not run in this case.

```
NOT(REGEX( Insured_ZipCode__c , "\\d{5}(-\\d{4})?"))
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to also check whether it has a value entered in it or not:

```
NOT(ISBLANK(Insured_ZipCode__c)) && NOT(REGEX( Insured_ZipCode__c , "\\d{5}(-\\d{4})?"))
```

So if you don't render it, it will be blank and will be ignored by the validation rule, but as soon as you enter a value (you render it), then it must match the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
AND(
NOT(REGEX( Insured_ZipCode__c , "\d{5}(-\d{4})?")),
Rendered = TRUE)

Comment: where is Rendered=True documented for use in the validation formulas ? I don't see it in the list of All Function Categories in the error condition formula editor.